# pass FILE pointer to C function

Tags: c, go

My C function takes address of FILE pointer (pointer to pointer that is, `FILE **fp`). I am calling this method from Go.
Can someone give me a example code line for calling convention in Go.

C library code (.so file will be created):

```
int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, FILE **fp){
*fp  = fopen (filename, mode);
 if (*fp ==NULL)
   return -1;
 return 0;
}
int fileread(FILE *fp,char *buff ){
        if((fp!=NULL)&&( fgets ( buff, 50, fp) != NULL ) )
        {
                return 0;
        }
  return -1;
}
int fileclose(FILE *fp){
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

```
import "C"
type (
        fileptr C.FILE
)

func opencfile(name string, mode string) int {
        var fp *fileptr
        return (int)(C.fileOpen(C.CString(name), C.CString(mode), C.FILE(&fp)));
}
```

I am getting error

> cannot convert _cgoBase2 (type **fileptr) to type _Ctype_struct__IO_FILE

Question:

1. Is this the right way to call C method?
2. how do I pass address of file pointer from Go? or how to resolve the the above error.

The called "C" method prototype is :

```
int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, FILE **fp);
```

---

UPDATE: here is my latest code:

C code (.c file)

```
#include "fileOp_lib.h"

int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, fileptr *out){
    FILE *fp  = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        *out = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    *out = (fileptr) fp;
    return 0;
}

int fileread(fileptr fp, char *buff){
    if( (fp != 0) && (fgets(buff, 50, (FILE*)fp) != NULL) )
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

int fileclose(fileptr fp){
    fclose((FILE*)fp);
    return 0;
}
```

header file (.h file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int fileptr;
int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, fileptr *out);
//int fileread(FILE *fp,char *buff ); temp. commented
//int fileclose(FILE *fp);
```

Go Code

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./SAMPLE/ -lfileop
#include "fileOp_lib.h"
*/
import "C"
type (
        fileptr uintptr
)

func opencfile(name string, mode string) int {
        var fp fileptr;
        return (int)(C.fileOpen(C.CString(name), C.CString(mode), (&fp)));
}


func main(){
        var e int;
        e = opencfile("data.txt","r");
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  What ***problem*** are you trying to solve where you've already decided that the solution is to open a file in Go and pass it to C as an open `FILE *` pointer?

Comment: I am getting an error, that posted in question. cannot convert _cgoBase2 (type **fileptr) to type _Ctype_struct__IO_FILE

Comment: @TippuR You are just restating your problem, but you didn't answer Andrew's question about why you are trying to use `FILE*` in Go to begin with. It looks like you are trying to type-cast a `FILE**` pointer to a `FILE` instance, which it is not, hence the convert error.

Comment: This is slightly restating the errors from your last question. The compiler error shows the type mismatch clearly. Why are you creating a new type then trying to convert it in the first place?

Comment: I added my C library code. C library 3 functions, opens, read, close. On read  I am planning to pass FIlE pointer which was created in open

Comment: Even if you could get this to compile without error, `fileOpen()` would be leaking the `FILE` object that `fileOpen()` outputs. You would need to pass `fp` to `fileClose()` to close the file and avoid a leak. You don't need access to the `FILE`'s innards from Go, so I would suggest NOT exposing direct access to the `FILE*` to Go at all. Have the C library hide the `FILE*` pointer using an opaque type instead, like `uintptr`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau. Yes, I will call close(). But to keep program simple, I am not calling close for now.

Comment: @JimB I need to either fix this compilation error, or know a right way to call my "c" library method. Let me know if there is a better way

Comment: @Remy Lebeau : I added my C method prototype, the 3rd argument is FILE **fp. So I am passing C.FILE(&fp). Let me know if there is a better way

Comment: @TippuR see the answer just posted

Comment: If you want to call this function as is, the correct type is `**C.FILE`.

Comment: `typedef unsigned int fileptr;`?!?!?  What makes you think a pointer can fit into an `int`?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than messing about with yet more layers, you can just call your original C code correctly from Go.  See [JimB's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819321/pass-file-pointer-to-c-function#comment116374252_65819321) or the example below.

Note that the original C code is ... not great, and given that there's nothing other than that C code, it would probably be better to use the Go I/O routines, which are much safer and easier to get right.  Presumably whatever real C code you have is substantially more complex.  Parts that you left out will likely require deep understanding of both C and Go to connect.

Here's code that compiles and runs (and creates an empty `file.txt`).

```golang
package main

// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// int fileOpen(char *filename, char *mode, FILE **fp) {
//      *fp = fopen(filename, mode);
//      if (*fp == NULL)
//              return -1;
//      return 0;
// }
//
// int fileread(FILE *fp, char *buff) {
//      if ((fp != NULL) && (fgets(buff, 50, fp) != NULL)) {
//              return 0;
//      }
//      return -1;
// }
//
// int fileclose(FILE *fp) {
//      fclose(fp);
//      return 0;
// }
import "C"

import (
        "fmt"
        "unsafe"
)

func opencfile(name string, mode string) (ret int, fp *C.FILE) {
        cname := C.CString(name)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cname))
        cmode := C.CString(mode)
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cmode))
        ret = int(C.fileOpen(cname, cmode, &fp))
        return
}

func main() {
        ret, fp := opencfile("file.txt", "w")
        if ret >= 0 {
                defer C.fileclose(fp)
        }
        fmt.Printf("result of opencfile was %d\n", ret)
}
```

Comment: *it would probably be better to use the Go I/O routines*  Indeed.  +1 for that alone.  Especially for someone who's already tried to put a pointer into an `int`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the correct syntax to pass a `FILE**` from Go to C (if it is even possible).  But, if you can change the C code, I would suggest NOT exposing *direct* access to an interop-incompatible type like `FILE` at all.  I would suggest something more like this instead:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uintptr_t fileptr;

int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, fileptr *out){
    FILE *fp  = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (*fp == NULL) {
        *out = 0;
        return -1;
    }
    *out = (fileptr) fp;
    return 0;
}

int fileread(fileptr fp, char *buff){
    if( (fp != 0) && (fgets(buff, 50, (FILE*)fp) != NULL) )
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

int fileclose(fileptr fp){
    fclose((FILE*)fp);
    return 0;
}
```

```golang
import "C"

...

var fp uintptr
C.fileOpen(..., &fp);
...
c.fileRead(fp, ...);
...
C.fileClose(fp);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code, but got "cannot use &fp (type *fileptr) as type *_Ctype_uint in argument to _Cfunc_fileOpen"

I tried possible ways I can think of like using C.uint , but couldn't figure out

Comment: @TippuR what does your declaration of `fileOpen()` on the Go side look like?

Comment: func opencfile(name string, mode string) int {
        var fp fileptr;
        return (int)(C.fileOpen(C.CString(name), C.CString(mode), (&fp)));
}

Comment: @TippuR no, I did not mean your Go function. I meant the declaration of the C function in Go

Comment: typedef unsigned int fileptr;
int fileOpen(char *filename, char* mode, fileptr *out);

Comment: @TippuR that is the declaration of the C function ON THE C SIDE. What is the declaration of the C function ON THE GO SIDE? I'm not familiar with Go, but don't you have to declare the function before you can call it?

Comment: I am really sorry, I didn't declare any declaration on go side. Let me add all of my code to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227621/discussion-between-tippur-and-remy-lebeau).

Comment: Why not use `typedef intptr_t fileptr;` instead of this `__int64` stuff? That's what this type is made for.

Comment: "I would suggest NOT exposing *direct* access to an interop-incompatible type like `FILE` at all." Indeed.  On a lot of systems, that would be impossible as the C `FILE` structure is opaque, and calling code might not be able to determine even the size of the `FILE` structure.

Comment: @Gerhardh because `(u)intptr_t` are optional in the C/C++ standards, so it is not guaranteed that all C/C++ compilers will have them available. But you are right, they would be better to use when available.